# set width of bootstrap popover not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create popovers that contain a table, but the table is being displayed outside of the popover. Trying to adjust the width of the popover content is not solving the problem. 

Setting styles for popover-content for width of max-width is not solving the problem. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

```js
    $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({
      container: 'body',
      html: true,
      content: function () {
        return $('#popover-content').html();
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<a href="#" class="mytooltip" data-toggle="popover" data-container="#wrap" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="auto right">
  <img src="\img\help.png" alt="?" style="width:20px;height:20px;border:0">
</a>

<div id="popover-content" class="hide" style="width: 800px; max-width: 100%;">
    <table style="width: 400px;">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>heading 1</th>
    <th>heading 2</th>
    <th>heading 3</th>
    <th>heading 4</th>
   </tr>
        </thead>
     <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>Content row 1 col 1</td>
    <td>Content row 1 col 2</td>
    <td>Content row 1 col 3</td>
    <td>Content row 1 col 4</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: @Renuka CE, thanks this actually solved the problem. It seems that overriding the default styling of the popover was sufficient. There's apparently no need to add the !important declaration. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please include the css .popover {max-width: 100% !important;}.Once popover on image it will add popover class to desired places. so you need to override the max-width value.

```js
$('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({
      container: 'body',
      html: true,
      content: function () {
        return $('#popover-content').html();
      }
    });
```

```css
.popover {
        max-width: 100% !important;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    

    <a href="#" class="mytooltip" data-toggle="popover" data-container="#wrap" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="auto right">
      <img src="http://91ef69bade70f992a001-b6054e05bb416c4c4b6f3b0ef3e0f71d.r93.cf3.rackcdn.com/sea-gull-100219122.jpg" alt="?" style="width:20px;height:20px;border:0">
    </a>

    <div id="popover-content" class="hide" style="width: 800px; max-width: 100%;">
        <table style="width: 400px;">
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>heading 1</th>
        <th>


heading 2</th>
        <th>heading 3</th>
        <th>heading 4</th>
       </tr>
            </thead>
         <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td>Content row 1 col 1</td>
        <td>Content row 1 col 2</td>
        <td>Content row 1 col 3</td>
        <td>Content row 1 col 4</td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
```